# Como converter um arquivo em formato javascript para formato ts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Sei que a linguagem TypeScript serve para compilar arquivos em JavaScript. Mas gostaria de saber se existe alguma ferramenta que possibilite fazer o inverso.

Existe alguma forma de converter um arquivo em JavaScript para uma estrutura em TypeScript, algo automático?

Para mim seria muito mais interessante poder trabalhar a partir da linguagem TypeScript, para refatorar um arquivo, e melhorar a lógica a partir disso, pois a versão que temos aqui está bem desorganizada, e tem uma estrutura muito complexa e bagunçada, acredito que passando para o TypeScript, poderei mesclar e melhorar algumas coisas, pois o TypeScript, é bem mais flexível neste sentido.

Eu estou tendo que recriar tudo manualmente em TypeScript, porém perco muito tempo tendo que revisar cada item, e cada trecho do código. Gostaria de poupar esforços e trabalhar a partir da versão antiga convertida para uma linguagem fortemente tipada, como é o TypeScript.

Comment: Eu não sei TypeScript, parece baseado em ECMAScript 4 em alguns pontos, talvez não vale apena transpilar JavaScript para TypeScript, o resultado não será o mais expectativo (por exemplo, o código poderia funcionar identicamente, mas não usaria muito dos recursos novos de TypeScript, como :TipoDeValor | ..., e tals). O resultado da conversão será tipo ilegível.

Comment: A linguagem typescript é "superior" a javascript, então qualque ferramenta que inventarem vai ter problemas para a conversão. Existem umas pessoas usando o resharp 9 para isso, se souber inglês, aqui uma boa lida: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/02/05/ways-and-advantages-of-migrating-javascript-code-to-typescript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, todo código JavaScript é um código TypeScript válido, então não há necessidade de transpilação inversa do ponto de vista do compilador.

Já com relação às ferramentas de edição e IDEs, não há necessidade de reescrever o código logo de imediato. Basta mudar a extensão de .js pra .ts e você já tem acesso a ferramentas como análise estática de tipos (ver exemplo abaixo), auto-complete e refatoração.

Exemplo 1:

```
// Usando TSC 2.0
if (typeof m === "number") {
    var v = m; //VS Code mostra 'm' e 'v' como do tipo number
    //...
}
```

Outra opção para não ter que reescrever o código todo antes de utilizar os benefícios do TypeScript é criando arquivos de declaração .d.ts. Nesses arquivos você especifica interfaces e as tipagens das suas funções e os editores podem utilizar essas declarações para te mostrar os tipos.

Exemplo 2:

Digamos que você tem um código javascript com essa função:

```
greet({
  greeting: "hello world",
  duration: 4000
});
```

Você pode criar um arquivo `minhaTipagem.d.ts` com a seguinte definição:

```
interface GreetingSettings {
  greeting: string;
  duration?: number;
  color?: string;
}

declare function greet(setting: GreetingSettings): void;
```

Com isso, os editores vão ver que quando você digitar a função `greet`, ela se trata de uma função que aceita um parâmetro do com a forma e tipagem de `GreetingSettings`.

Assim você pode já utilizar a tipagem do TypeScript, escrevendo relativamente pouco código.

Comment: Eu entendo o que você diz, mas o que quero é deixá-lo com menos cara de linguagem de máquina, e mais organizado, para então depois compilá-lo... queria evitar o fatídico trabalho de reescrever tudo na unha.

Comment: Ok. Não entendo o que você quer, então. Poderia editar a pergunta com algum exemplo?

Comment: A liguagem TypeScript, além de superior tem uma semântica mais organizada, é bem diferente. É exatamente isso que eu quero trazer, quando digo que quero converter um arquivo em JavaScript para o formato TypeScript, não é só mudar a extensão do arquivo.

Comment: Tá. Deixa eu ver se eu entendi direito. Você quer mudar seu código para conceitos que foram adicionados no ES6 e Typescript, como Classes, funções lambda e template strings, certo?

Existe uma ferramenta chamada Lebab ( https://lebab.io/ ) que faz o inverso do Babel e transforma código ES5 em ES6. 

Não é a mesma coisa que transformar em TypeScript pq os conceitos de Tipo e Interfaces, por exemplo, não existem em versão alguma do Javascript.

Verifica se é mais ou menos isso que você quer, que eu atualizo a minha resposta :D

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem uma grande base de código Javascript o recomendável é usar o [Salsa](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Salsa). Basicamente ele pede ajuda ao JSDoc e traz o poder do typescript para o código javascript.

*[Mas e o tipos?]*: **JSDoc ao resgate!**

Você poderá usar typescript definitions das bibliotecas, comentários jsdoc e ter mais ou menos o mesmo poder dos tipos do typescript, e isso tudo sem a necessidade de mudar sua base de código JS. E claro, também poderá misturar arquivos js e ts no mesmo projeto sem problema!

Aqui projeto nodejs de exemplo: https://github.com/AbraaoAlves/feathersjs_typescript_sample
Repare no arquivo [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/AbraaoAlves/feathersjs_typescript_sample/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L9) e opcionalmente uma mãozinha do [ts-node](https://github.com/AbraaoAlves/feathersjs_typescript_sample/blob/master/package.json#L24) para não perder tempo gerando arquivo.

Comment: Minha opinião: Salsa irá matar o BabelJS